# How to generate nested JSON with SQL

Tags: sql, json

Can you assist me with the following query:

I have two tables

[sDocumentManagement].[tDocuments]

[sDocumentManagement].[tDocumentAttachments]

Every entry in the documents table is for different Document and the PK is DocumentID. In the table for DocumentAttachments we can have one or more attachments with FK - DocumentID.

What I want to achieve is the following.

```
[
  {
    DocumentID: 1,
    Something: 'blb',
    Attachments: [
      {
        AttachmentID: 1,
        SomethingElse: '23232'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    DocumentID: 2,
    Something: 'blb',
    Attachments: [
      {
        AttachmentID: 12,
        SomethingElse: '23232'
      },
      {
        AttachmentID: 13,
        SomethingElse: '23232'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to take all the information from both tables.

I tried the following queries

```
SELECT @DocumentsJSON = (
        SELECT *
        FROM [sDocumentManagement].[tDocuments]
        LEFT JOIN [sDocumentManagement].[tDocumentAttachments] ON [tDocuments].DocumentID = [tDocumentAttachments].DocumentID
    FOR JSON PATH
    )




   SELECT @DocumentsJSON = (
    SELECT
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM [sDocumentManagement].[tDocumentAttachments]
        WHERE [tDocumentAttachments].DocumentID = [tDocuments].DocumentID
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) Attachments
    , *
    FROM [sDocumentManagement].[tDocuments]
    FOR JSON PATH
    )
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried this two queries, but still did not test them(check the original post)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution:

```
SELECT @DocumentsJSON = (
       SELECT *,
       (
       SELECT * FROM [sDocumentManagement].[tDocumentAttachments] ATTACHMENTS
       WHERE ATTACHMENTS.DocumentID = DOCS.DocumentID
       FOR JSON AUTO
       ) DocumentAttachments
       FROM [sDocumentManagement].[tDocuments] DOCS
       WHERE DOCS.OrganizationID = @OrganizationID
       FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Documents')
)
```

but there is another problem.

No matter I declare the @DocumentsJSON NVarChar(MAX) OUTPUT,
the SQL is returning only 4500characters for DocumentsJSON ?
Any idea where is the problem ?